# Exception on Image.FromFile statement c# framework 3.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Hi everybody i am new in this forum,i have this problem,i am using visual studio 2008 framework 3.5,i have to copy an image from a server to my computer,e then trasform it from gif file to gpj. so i have these lines of code to do it

```
var gifFile = Image.FromFile(NetworkItineraryPathAndFilename);
gifFile.Save(LocalItineraryPathAndFilename, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Instruction 1 give me the exception 'System.OutOfMemoryException,i saw the other answer for the same kind of error but it didn't help me.

thank you,and sorry for my english

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you dispose the gifFile after using it. Images in RAM are quite expensive in RAM usage. So take care that you don't try to load huge files and always dispose them after using it to free the allocated memory.

```
using(var gifFile = Image.FromFile(NetworkItineraryPathAndFilename))
{
    gifFile.Save(LocalItineraryPathAndFilename, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

Comment: @Sudhakar and guess what, you both are thinking in wrong direction (as Sriram says),

Comment: So you may share your solution with us? @FaisalHafeez

Comment: @Sudhakar and thefiloe, Check my answer :)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Thanks for your valuable inputs. removing my answer... :)

Comment: I tryed this solution i get the same exception :(

Comment: So @SriramSakthivel was right. It may has the wrong format. Try another image.

Comment: No i have many images in that directory ,and i can open e read with double click,also my collegues do with the same system configuration i have ,but i can't!!!they are gif file of 4kb of size

Answer (score 1):

Image.FromFile is clearly documented. It will throw `OutOfMemoryException` when

> The file does not have a valid image format.
>   -or-
>   GDI+ does not support the pixel format of the file.

Of course, it is misleading but...

Take a look at [Image.FromFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Well that might be one possibility. But I've personally got an OutOfMemoryException by not disposing image objects. So we can't say. But all in all your answer seems more realistic.

Comment: @thefiloe I don't think so. You can use 2GB of memory default in 32bit process. You mean your app ate all 2GB from not being disposing the image?

Comment: Yes. I've loaded a directory full of images within a loop without disposing them.

Comment: The file has a valid format it is a gif file , it is also 4 KB of size,the second point of msdn(GDI+ doesn't support the pixel format of the file), i can't understand ,i just know my collegues with the same system configuration windows 7 32 bit 4 GIGa ram memory don't have this exceptions

Comment: So what's your machine info?

Comment: i have a laptop fujitsu,the operating system is windows 7 professional 32 bit, 4 giga memory ram,do you need some other details?

Comment: @marcocicerani Can you try with some other image? If that works fine we can conclude that particular image is broken ?

Comment: i tryed with some other images , but i still get this exception

Comment: @marcocicerani So you can't load any Image? I'd suggest you to restart your laptop and see if that can fix.

Comment: i have this problem since three days,so i have already restarted many times the laptop,it doesn't change anything